# Generalized julia sets and simple connectedness

Tags: general-topology, fractals, visualization, complex-dynamics

**BACKGROUND:** The **Mandelbrot set** is the set of complex numbers $c$ for which the sequence obtained by iterating $z \mapsto z^2 + c$ starting at $0$ remains bounded. For a complex number $c$, we can define the **Julia set** $J_c$ similarly, as the set of complex numbers $x$ for which the sequence obtained by iterating $z \mapsto z^2 + c$ starting at $x$ remains bounded. (To see some images of these beautiful sets, look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julia_set#Quadratic_polynomials).)

Anyway, a famous theorem (I think Fatou-Julia) states that $J_c$ is simply connected whenever $c$ is in the Mandelbrot set.

I believe this fact generalizes to **multi-brot sets** and their corresponding collections of Julia sets, which are described by using a larger integer exponent than 2. For instance, the 3-brot set and corresponding Julia sets $J^3_c$ iterate the cubic $z\mapsto z^3 + c$.

**QUESTION:** I'm curious about non-integer exponents. I've made some computer drawings of the sets $J^\alpha_c$ for a few non-integer exponents $\alpha$. These technically aren't Julia sets anymore, since the map being iterated is no longer a polynomial, but they still look like gorgeous fractals, although parts of their boundaries appear smooth. But they don't look connected, whether or not $c$ is in the $\alpha$-brot set. Look by the negative real axis (left) in the image below for an example.

I wonder if anyone can confirm my suspicion that the simple connectedness result doesn't generalize to non-integer exponents. If anyone's curious as to the application, the reason simple connectedness is important is because a simply connected set can be drawn extremely efficiently using contour-tracing.

[image]
Above: the set $J^\alpha_c$ for $\alpha=3.11$, $c \approx 0.596+0.596i$.

Comment: While it's try that Julia sets for functions of the form $z^n+c$ are connected when $n$ is a positive integer, that's not true for negative $n$ or even for polynomials. Your functions (with non-integer exponents) are much more complicated and trying to define a Julia set is not so trivial. The main problem is the branch cut, as you can see in your picture [highlighted here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhMRv.png). I'd recommend taking [a look at this](http://www.righto.com/2011/12/new-multi-branch-algorithm-to-render.html) to get some more clear ideas on how to proceed.

Comment: Amazing, thank you for the resource! Not only is my question answered but I now have a better understanding of complex exponentiation!